# Regex - how to retrieve words after last occurrence of keywords

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to retrieve all the words that appear after the last occurrence of list of keywords

my keywords - and, or , not

for examples

```
input = "tom hanks and hugh jack"
output = hugh jack

input ="tom hanks and hugh jack or bill bob"
output = bill bob

input ="tom hanks and hugh jack or bill bob not brad pitt"
output = brad pitt
```

Comment: Can the keywords change or will they always be "and", "or", and "not"?

Comment: these are the only three keywords

Comment: Something in these lines `input.split(/\b(?:and|or|not)\b/).pop();`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That is genius; I'd use that solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
var output =  input.replace(/.*\b(?:and|or|not) /, '');
```

The `?:` simply prevents a back-reference from being created.  Not strictly necessary, but slightly more efficient (at the cost of being, perhaps, slightly less readable).

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex will do:

```
.*(and|or|not)\s(.*)
```

It must be used with a greedy flag, and using a match. Then access the second group retrieved with the match.

Comment: This will result in leading space characters in `output`